# How to use JSON array to create parameters in single POST request

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter

I am obtaining a list of values from JSON response from a previous call. The values obtained look like the following:

```
VAR_ResponseID_1=123
VAR_ResponseID_2=234
VAR_ResponseID_3=345
VAR_ResponseID_4=456
VAR_ResponseID_5=567
VAR_ResponseID_6=678
VAR_ResponseID_7=789
VAR_ResponseID_ALL=123,234,345,456,567,678,789
VAR_ResponseID_matchNr=7
```

I want to use those values as parameters in a following POST request and so far was able to build the request as follow:

```
responseIDs[0]=${VAR_ResponseID_1}  URL Encode=true text/plain=true
responseIDs[1]=${VAR_ResponseID_2}  URL Encode=true text/plain=true
responseIDs[2]=${VAR_ResponseID_3}  URL Encode=true text/plain=true
responseIDs[3]=${VAR_ResponseID_4}  URL Encode=true text/plain=true
responseIDs[4]=${VAR_ResponseID_5}  URL Encode=true text/plain=true
responseIDs[5]=${VAR_ResponseID_6}  URL Encode=true text/plain=true
responseIDs[6]=${VAR_ResponseID_7}  URL Encode=true text/plain=true
```

However, the number of VAR_ResponseIDs is never the same and varies.
Is there any way in which I can build the parameters in the following POST request dynamically, based on the number of responses I've got from the JSON response?

For example, if there are VAR_ResponseID_matchNr=9, how can I build the params in the POST request by reading that values and indexing the responseIDs accordingly, i.e.:
responseIDs[0] to responseIDs[8], and then matching the values of the variables with the parameter created?

Answer (score 0):

You can build the request body dynamically using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and the following Groovy code:

```
def data = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments()

1.upto(vars.get('VAR_ResponseID_matchNr') as int, index -> {
    def argument = new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument('responseIDs[' + (index - 1) + ']', vars.get('VAR_ResponseID_' + index), false, 'text/plain')
    data.addArgument(argument)
})

sampler.setArguments(data)
```

see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) to learn what do these `sampler` and `vars` mean.

Comment: Hi Dimitri, 

Thank you so much for the help. I will give the snippet a go.

I somehow knew you will be the one to answer that question. 

Thanks,
Niki

Comment: Hi Dimitri, 
The POST request I am trying to do has the following arguments:
'responseIDs[0] ${VAR_ResponseID_1} true text/plain true
responseIDs[1] ${VAR_ResponseID_2} true text/plain true
responseIDs[2] ${VAR_ResponseID_3} true text/plain true
responseIDs[3] ${VAR_ResponseID_4} true text/plain true
responseIDs[4] ${VAR_ResponseID_5} true text/plain true
responseIDs[5] ${VAR_ResponseID_6} true text/plain true
responseIDs[6] ${VAR_ResponseID_7} true text/plain true
showAttachments true true text/plain true
reportCallbackConnectionId ${VAR_ConnectionId} true text/plain true' 
...

Comment: ... and the POST request didn't send the parameters(arguments) at all with the snippet put in the JSR223 PreProcessor